# Fast computation of the prime zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods, algorithms, zeta-functions

What is the state of the art for numerically computing the [prime zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function)? There are several papers on the subject for the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function), such as [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042700003368). [This paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01933420) on the subject dates to 1968. Is there more recent work?

I am especially interested in the region near the [natural boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation#Natural_boundary).

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't claim "the state of the art", but there's a simple idea (present in some form in [*High precision computation of Hardy-Littlewood constants*](http://www.math.u-bordeaux1.fr/%7Ecohen/hardylw.dvi) by H. Cohen): for $\Re s>0$ and $s$ not a singularity, $$P(s)=\sum_{p\leqslant N}p^{-s}+\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\log\zeta_{p>N}(ns),$$ where we set $\zeta_{p>N}(s)=\zeta(s)\prod_{p\leqslant N}(1-p^{-s})$ and take $N$ suitably large (to make the last sum above converge quickly: for $s=\sigma+i\tau$ we have $\log\zeta_{p>N}(ns)\in\mathcal{O}(N^{-n\sigma})$ as $n\to\infty$).